# Error when importing numpy (SyntaxError)

Tags: python, numpy, syntax-error

I suddenly obtained the following error when i tried to import `NumPy`:

[image: Print screen with error]

More specifically, it shows up when I type:

```
import numpy as np
```

or just:

```
import numpy
```

It also happens in the Python console as follows:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Py27_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Py27_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Py27_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .npyio import *
  File "C:\Py27_64\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1162
    x                                    % (str(X.dtype), format))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

No `NumPy` functions were called to get this error. It only happens when importing `NumPy`. Note that I was able to successfully work with `NumPy` earlier.

All other Python functions work well. I tried reinstalling `NumPy` but didn't work. I work in Python 2.7 64bit with `PyScripter`.
I didn't install anything new recently, it just happened suddenly.

Comment: Does this also happen when you type `import numpy` into a python console?

Comment: Yesy, it also happens in python console - I updated my question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you use a Python 2 edition of numpy.

Comment: Numpy installed with "numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl", so it seems to be OK with my 2.7.12 Python 64bit.

Comment: From where is the wheel?

Comment: Took it from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/dp2ng7en/numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Try to recompile it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I just reinstalled everything (Python itself, all my Libs, PyScripter). It works again.
Thank You guys.